# Polars Expression for Aggregation of Sums Across Variable Length Groups

Tags: python, python-polars

This is a two part question. Firstly how to a achieve a polars expression such that:

```
import datetime
import polars as pl
pl.Config.set_tbl_rows(100)

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D"],
        "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
        "category": ["X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y"],
    }
)

expr = ...alias("feature")
df = df.with_column(expr)
print(df)
```

yields

```
shape: (12, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬─────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ value ┆ category┆ feature              │ 
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---                  │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ str     ┆ f64                  │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ A   ┆ 1     ┆ X       ┆ null                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ 2     ┆ X       ┆ null                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ 3     ┆ X       ┆ null                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A   ┆ 4     ┆ X       ┆ null                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 5     ┆ Y       ┆ null                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 6     ┆ Y       ┆ null                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B   ┆ 7     ┆ Y       ┆ null                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C   ┆ 8     ┆ X       ┆ 2.7                  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C   ┆ 9     ┆ X       ┆ 2.7                  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C   ┆ 10    ┆ X       ┆ 2.7                  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ D   ┆ 11    ┆ Y       ┆ 1.27777777           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ D   ┆ 12    ┆ Y       ┆ 1.27777777           │
└─────┴───────┴─────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

such that `feature` is the ratio of the sums of the current id to the previous id in that particular category.
that is:

```
2.7 = (8 + 9 + 10) / (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)
2.7 = (sum of value id "C") / (sum of value in previously occurring group in category `X`. That is, `id == "A"`)
```

And then the second part:

I'd like to generalise this to rather than a ratio against the previous group's sum, to a ratio against an `ewm_mean` of the sum of all previous groups.

For the first part, I was able to achieve the result when the length of unique `id`s was constant. In this case you can shift by this lenght after a sum over `id` and `category` window expression. I cannot fathom how to achieve the result with variable length groups for either the first part or the second part.

I appreciate any response, so thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible in one expression, at a glance. I was able to solve part 1 with the following:

- Create a separate aggregated DataFrame with each subsum by category
  mainly, and id. Keeping the order is important as well.
- `df.groupby("category", "id", maintain_order=True).agg(feature=pl.sum("value"))`

```
┌──────────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ category ┆ id  ┆ feature │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ str      ┆ str ┆ i64     │
╞══════════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ X        ┆ A   ┆ 10      │
│ Y        ┆ B   ┆ 18      │
│ X        ┆ C   ┆ 27      │
│ Y        ┆ D   ┆ 23      │
└──────────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

- Do a division of the new column by the `shift` of it, over the `category`, to get the desired values.
- This works regardless of the # of rows per group since we're working on an aggregated df now, one row per group, and it's been sorted properly with `maintain_order` above.
- `(...).with_columns((pl.col("feature") / pl.col("feature").shift()).over("category"))`

```
┌──────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ category ┆ id  ┆ feature  │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ str      ┆ str ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ X        ┆ A   ┆ null     │
│ Y        ┆ B   ┆ null     │
│ X        ┆ C   ┆ 2.7      │
│ Y        ┆ D   ┆ 1.277778 │
└──────────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

- Do a join of the original `df` on this "feature" df to broadcast the values properly.

Overall:

```py
df.join(
    df.groupby("category", "id", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(feature=pl.sum("value"))
    .with_columns((pl.col("feature") / pl.col("feature").shift()).over("category")),
    on=["id", "category"],
)
```

```
shape: (12, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ value ┆ category ┆ feature  │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ str      ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ A   ┆ 1     ┆ X        ┆ null     │
│ A   ┆ 2     ┆ X        ┆ null     │
│ A   ┆ 3     ┆ X        ┆ null     │
│ A   ┆ 4     ┆ X        ┆ null     │
│ B   ┆ 5     ┆ Y        ┆ null     │
│ B   ┆ 6     ┆ Y        ┆ null     │
│ B   ┆ 7     ┆ Y        ┆ null     │
│ C   ┆ 8     ┆ X        ┆ 2.7      │
│ C   ┆ 9     ┆ X        ┆ 2.7      │
│ C   ┆ 10    ┆ X        ┆ 2.7      │
│ D   ┆ 11    ┆ Y        ┆ 1.277778 │
│ D   ┆ 12    ┆ Y        ┆ 1.277778 │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

As for part 2, I think the procedure would be similar, but the `agg` would need to be a `ewm_mean` and the `with_columns` would need to be some type of `cum` (cumulative) expression instead of just a `shift`. An example df / output would be appreciated for this part as well.